# Power BI subtotal rows

Tags: statistics, analytics, powerbi, powerquery

I want to change a view of a table. i have attached a picture below:
[image]

what I like to do is only show the last Percentage column and hide the other 2 sub-subtotal percentage columns that are filled with -100% or infinity. this is the cause of the percentage column being a calculation between year 2017 and 2018.

can someone explain to me how i can hide/delete the first 2 percentage rows and keep the last one?

thanks in advance

Comment: I've wanted to do this before too. I suspect there isn't a clean way to do this currently. Might be advisable to post it as an idea for the Microsoft devs: https://ideas.powerbi.com

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a plan! I'll be posting the idea there but in the mean time do you know a, maybe, not so clean way of doing this since you have had the same "problem"

Comment: I'v put a idea up at power BI devs: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/34117237-a-easy-way-to-edit-the-table-visual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the cleanest way but you could just slide the column widths as small as possible which has the effect of "hiding" them

[image]

Comment: thanks! looks like an actually good work-around. but of course not the cleanest way as you already said. I am going to close this topic and select your answer as The answer thanks for the help!